# Different Kernel in DomU than in Dom0 on xen

Tags: xen

If my Dom0 on Xen is kernel 2.6.18 with xen 3.3.1 can i boot a, say, 2.6.34 kernel in a DomU ?
Background: 2.6.18 runs like a charm on Dom0. Don't want to update here, because there is special Hardware on the Host (ISDN-Card, etc.). Building a new kernel with this Modules for Dom0 is pain !

But i want to upgrade some DomU's to a newer Kernel...

Comment: That pygrub stuff?

Comment: And your distribution is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should normally work. (even for PVs). For PVs the XEN-version contained in the kernel is more important than the kernel-version itselv.

I have currently XEN 3.2.3 (SLES10 SP4) with PV DomU ranging from SLES9 over CentOS 4, 5 to SLES11 SP1 (XEN 3.0 up to XEN 4.0). A problem just arises with RedHat 6 - but that is due to a new compress format of the kernel that SLES10 SP4 is not able to decode (it runs well as HVM or using SLES11 SP2 as Dom0).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about PV, but if you're using HVM you can certainly have a different kernel.

Either way it's easy to try. Shutdown the domU and make a copy (or snapshot if you're using lvm) of the domU's disk image. Turn it back on and upgrade the kernel.

If anything doesn't work, just revert.